# MVC5 internationalization of URLs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internationalization, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

How can the URLs in an MVC application be localized.

So for example, I would have different URLs depending on the languate

- EN:  .../user/...
- DE:  .../Benutzer/...

I not only want this for nice URLs, but also generate my Breadcrumbs from this URLs, so this will genereate me something like:

- EN:  Home -> User -> ..
- DE:  Überischt -> Benutzer -> ....

I looked into the Routconfig, but didn't find any options for internationalization. Do I have to define a spezifice route for each internationalized URL?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to make localized URL that are convention-based beyond adding a localized variation for each route. Instead, you have to build a [custom `RouteBase`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32839796) that maps the URLs to route combinations based on the current culture. You can also make the reverse routes by overriding `GetVirtualPath` so that your `ActionLink` calls will build the correct URL according to the culture.

It works best to add the culture to the beginning of the URL, and use an initializer in the `Application_BeginRequest` event to set the culture based on the URL.

As for building breadcrumbs you could use [MvcSiteMapProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider), which supports localization.

**Full Disclosure**: I am a major contributor of MvcSiteMapProvider.